# Adding Boolean column in pandas dataframe for Date_1 rows > Date_2 rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a forecast date column and a completed date column in a pandas dataframe. I want to add a column that shows if the completed date was greater than the forecast date, i.e. late/not late.

Beginner, so I've got this bit

```
Late_Not_Late = np.where(df["Forecast_Date"] > df("Completed_Date"], True, False)
```

Am struggling with the other lines I need.

Comment: You can just use `df["Late_Not_Late"] = df["Forecast_Date"] > df("Completed_Date"]`.

Comment: Thank you will have a go

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df['Late_Not_Late'] = np.where(df["Forecast_Date"] > df["Completed_Date"],True,False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is

```
df['Late_not_late'] = df.Forecast_Date > df.Completed_Date
```